# Double-clicking Ditto clipboard manager clip doesn't always paste it in active window (Solved – Wait 2 seconds)

Tags: windows, clipboard, ditto

If you double-click a Ditto clipboard manager clip, it should paste it into the currently active window. Sometimes, I would notice that it would activate and paste it to the wrong window.

Answer (score 2):

I found a developer's comment:

> “When Ditto is on top, it will poll the system for who has focus,
> currently this happens every 2 seconds, if you switch active apps
> within this amount of time it will set focus to the wrong app.”

https://sourceforge.net/p/ditto-cp/discussion/287510/thread/f74b08fb/

After you select a window, you just have to wait a couple seconds for it to become the active one.

(Also, note that Options > General > “Paste Clip in active window after selection” has to be checked. It should however be on by default).